# Ember integration test click not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, integration-testing, qunit

I have the following code in my integration test.

```
module 'Admin page when logged in',
  setup: ->
    App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter
    signIn()
    visit "/admin"
  teardown: ->
    signOut()
    App.reset()

test "new button click", ->
  click("a.new-place")
  andThen ->
    equal(find('h1').text(), 'New Place')
```

I have done the setup of the test helpers appropriately hence I do have access to the visit and click helpers. However the click helper doesn't actually trigger the click or the transition to the appropriate route is not made. 
Putting a debugger, shows that the ".new-place" link does exist. 
Even trying with the following syntax doesn't work.

```
test "new button click", ->
    click("a.new-place").then ->
      equal(find("h1").text(), "New Place")
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE:**

Okay I have got this to work, but still getting errors. Apparently moving the visit link within the test solves the issue. 
However I am getting the following error have click.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushObject' of null
```

Not exactly sure what this is.

**Update #2**

```
<div class="admin-container">
  {{#link-to 'functions.new' classNames="new-function"}}
    New Function
  {{/link-to}}
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to test? Without seeing what this is testing, there’s no way to say where that error is coming from.

Comment: What do you mean by what it is testing? It's testing that the link in the template, see above, goes to the correct route. This works properly, however the tests are failing for this. Do you want to see any specific files? Thanks